# SystemC - How can I get the module name to which sc_signal connected?

Tags: systemc

I'd like to print out the name of sc_module to which sc_signal connected.

How can I get the module name, "module_a" in the following code, from "sig_out"?

```cpp
#include "systemc.h"

class sig_if : virtual public sc_interface
{
};

class my_sig : public sc_module, public sig_if
{
public:
    my_sig(sc_module_name nm) : sc_module(nm)
    {
    }
};

SC_MODULE(test_module)
{
    sc_port<sig_if> out;

    SC_CTOR(test_module)
    {
    }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    test_module module_a("module_a");
    my_sig sig_out("sig_out");

    module_a.out(sig_out);
    // std::cout << sig_out.get_parent() << std::endl;

    sc_start();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override `sc_interface::register_port()` in the `my_sig` class to save a reference to the bound port. The parent of the bound port is the module that contains the port.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "systemc.h"

class sig_if : virtual public sc_interface
{
};

class my_sig : public sc_module, public sig_if
{
public:
    my_sig(sc_module_name nm) : sc_module(nm), bound_port(NULL)
    {
    }

    void register_port(sc_port_base& port, const char*) {
        bound_port = &port;
    }

    sc_object* get_bound_module() const {
        assert(bound_port);
        return bound_port->get_parent_object();
    };

    sc_port_base* bound_port;
};

SC_MODULE(test_module)
{
    sc_port<sig_if> out;

    SC_CTOR(test_module)
    {
    }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    test_module module_a("module_a");
    my_sig sig_out("sig_out");

    module_a.out(sig_out);

    sc_start(0, SC_NS);

    std::cout << sig_out.get_bound_module()->name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints the name of `module_a`. Note that `sig::get_bound_module()` can only be called *after* elaboration, that is, after `sc_start()` has been called, because `sc_interface::register_port()` is only called during elaboration.